# Could I create a provisioning profile just with certificate and private key? (without apple developer site)

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I have a valid certificate and private key in my key chain access.
And I don't have access to apple developer account for login to site (or login with xcode).
Can I create a custom provisioning profile for my valid app id?

Update 1:
What exactly keys/certificates is needed to create a provisioning profile? (e.g Apple developer private key)

Comment: To create a *provisioning profile* you need access to a Apple Developer portal.  Its purpose is to allow installation of the app on developer devices for testing.  You don't need one to install on the simulator.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have valid developer account to create a provisioning profile.  Also the certificate you have in your keychain must belong to same developer account. for more details please follow apple document or you can refer this [blogpost](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/ios-code-signing-provisioning-in-a-nutshell-d5b247760bef)

Answer (score 0):

No! Provisioned profiles **MUST** signed with Apple private keys. so, it just could be created in Apple Developer portal.
 (even you have valid developer account or ...,  you need apple developer protal)